# Rendering a view behind another - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, pdfkit

I am wanting to render a view behind the current view so I can export it at a later date. I have found code on how to do this however it doesn't seem to work.

```
let charts = MatchReportView(homeTeam: homeTeam, awayTeam: awayTeam)

let pdfVC = UIHostingController(rootView: charts)
pdfVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

//Render the view behind all other views
let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
rootVC?.addChild(pdfVC)
rootVC?.view.insertSubview(pdfVC.view, at: 0)
```

I then go to render that view as a PDF, I'm unsure as to whether I need rootVC? or pdfVC in the next bit of code, however neither generate the desired view.

```
let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8.5 * 72.0, height: height))
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     do {
         try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
            context.beginPage()
            rootVC?.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext) //should this be rootVC? or pdfVC
         })
         print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
     } catch {
         print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
     }
 }
```

If I write, rootVC?.view.layer.render....., I get a pdf of the main view, not the one that should be rendered behind, so I know my generator is working! If I use pdfVC I get a blank document, but again is definitely rendering, just rendering an empty document. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need controller for that, you can just render view-by-view in same PDF context, ie. the "behind" view render first and all others after it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Asperi would you be able to show some code on how I would achieve this?